# Show orthogonal matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Suppose $U$ is an $n \times n$ ($n \in \Bbb Z_+$) orthogonal matrix. Show that $U$ is invertible.

I understand for $U$ to be orthogonal, the columns of $U$ must form a linearly independent set. Do I need to expand further or is this sufficient to show that $U$ is invertible?

Comment: Demonstrate that linear independence for the sake of completeness. Other than that, good to go.

Comment: The standard definition of orthogonal matrix is $UU^T = U^TU = I$; thus $U^{-1} = U^T$ and you're already there.  So are you sure you've got your question right?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I believe that it can also be proved via linear independence of the columns of U, though in a more roundabout way. My complete proof: Suppose U is an n x n orthogonal matrix
1. Columns of U form LI set (proof follows)

c1u1 + ... + cpup = 0 for scalars c1, ..., cp
(c1u1 + ... + cpup) * u1 = 0 * u1 = 0
= (c1u1)* u1 + ... + (cpup) * u1
= c1(u1 * u1) + ... + cp(up * u1)
Since u1 orthogonal to u2, ... , up
= c1(u1 * u1) = 0

Since u1 is nonzero, u1*u1 is also nonzero, so c1 = 0
By same logic, c2 = ... = cp = 0

2. Therefore U is invertible

Comment: I guess my question would be, "What is your definition of orthogonal matrix?"